# ¿Cómo actuan las funciones lambda en este código?

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda, callback

Si yo le quito a las funciones encargadas de escribir los números en la `StringVar` la función lambda, al momento de ejecutarse el programa ya aparecen escritos los números sin que yo presione los botones, en cambio con las funciones lambda espera a que yo presione el botón para escribir.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Calculator")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.geometry("495x440")
root.config(bg="white")
frame=tk.Frame(root,width=495,height=440,bg="powderblue").place(x=0,y=98)
text = tk.StringVar()
textshow = tk.StringVar()

def write(number):
    if len(text.get()) <= 15 and number != ".":
        text.set(text.get()+number)
        textshow.set(text.get())    

screen =tk.Label(borderwidth=10,relief="sunken",textvariable=textshow,width=16,height=1,bg="powderblue",font=("Arial",37),anchor="e").place(x=4,y=0)
button_7=tk.Button(frame,text="7",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("7"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=0,y=100)
button_8=tk.Button(frame,text="8",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("8"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=124,y=100)
button_9=tk.Button(frame,text="9",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("9"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=248,y=100)
button_4=tk.Button(frame,text="4",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("4"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=0,y=168)
button_5=tk.Button(frame,text="5",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("5"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=124,y=168)
button_6=tk.Button(frame,text="6",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("6"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=248,y=168)
button_1=tk.Button(frame,text="1",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("1"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=0,y=236)
button_2=tk.Button(frame,text="2",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("2"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=124,y=236)
button_3=tk.Button(frame,text="3",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("3"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=248,y=236)
button_0=tk.Button(frame,text="0",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("0"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=124,y=304)
button_coma = tk.Button(frame,text=".",width=6,font=("Arial",25),borderwidth=0,command=lambda:write("."),activebackground="gray").place(x=0,y=304)

Boton_Division=tk.Button(frame,text="/",width=6,font=("Arial",25),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=372,y=100)
Boton_Multiplication=tk.Button(frame,text="X",width=6,font=("Arial",25),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=372,y=168)
Boton_Subtraction=tk.Button(frame,text="-",width=6,font=("Arial",25),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=372,y=236)
Boton_Sum=tk.Button(frame,text="+",width=6,font=("Arial",25),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=372,y=304)
button_clear=tk.Button(frame,text="Clear",width=6,font=("Arial",25),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=248,y=304)
button_equal = tk.Button(frame,text="=",width=6,font=("Arial",25),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=372,y=372)
button_delete = tk.Button(frame,text="Delete",width=19,font=("Arial",25),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=0,y=372)
root.tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Al widget `tkinter.Button` se le puede pasar mediante el argumento `command` de su inicializador **un objeto ejecutable (callable) que será llamado cuando el botón sea pulsado**.

En tu caso ese objeto es la función `write`. El problema es que dicha función **necesita un parámetro obligatorio** (`number`). Este parámetro ha de ser pasado si o si cuando el botón llama a la función y aquí tenemos el problema

### ¿Cómo pasamos el argumento al objeto `Button` para que a su vez él lo proporcione a la función cuando sea llamada?

El constructor de `Button` no proporciona manera alguna de pasar un iterable o diccionario (**kwargs) con los argumentos, como si ocurre con `threading.Thread` por ejemplo:

```
threading.Thread(target=foo, args=(arg1, arg2, ...), kwargs={arg3=bar})
```

Ante este problema, es muy común cometer el siguiente error:

```
tk.Button(command=write("1"))
```

pero lo que ocurre en este caso es que en la asignación `command=write("1")`, como en cualquier otra asignación, se evaluá la parte derecha, es decir `write("1")` y el objeto resultante se asigna al nombre `command`. Esto **significa llamar a la función `write`** (por eso ves los números de inicio en tu `Entry`, porque la función se llama al instanciar cada botón). Pero además, dicha función retorna `None` (como toda función por defecto en Python), por lo que lo anterior queda realmente como:

```
tk.Button(command=None)
```

Lógicamente esto es un error, dado que **el botón no hará nada cuando sea pulsado si el objeto no es *callable***.

No es difícil en este punto entender que la clave está en pasar un callable que no necesite argumento obligatorio alguno. La respuesta a este problema  es **envolver nuestra función con otra función** que se encargará de llamarla y retornar su salida cuando sea llamada:

```
def envoltura():
    return write("1") 

tk.Button(command=envoltura)
```

Ahora el botón recibe como callback una referencia al objeto `envoltura` que no requiere argumentos, al se llama cuando el evento click tiene lugar en el botón. La función `envoltura` simplemente se dedica a ejecutar `write("1")` y a retornar lo que ésta le retorna.

Dado que realmente no necesitamos una función con nombre y es un poco pesado hacer lo anterior para muchos botones, se suele usar una función `lambda` o anónima. Esta función es totalmente equivalente a lo anterior, solo que no tiene un nombre explícitamente asociado a ella (`envoltura`), identificador que no vamos a usar y que no necesitamos que esté en nuestro espacio de nombres estorbando:

```
lambda: write("1")
```

el hecho de pasar un argumento a `write` diferente según el botón pulsado permite que la función haga algo distinto según el botón.

---

Si nos importa la eficiencia es recomendable usar `functools.partial` para estos casos. Su funcionamiento es el mismo, crear una envoltura sobre nuestra función, pero tiene algunas ventajas, por ejemplo es mucho más simple pasar argumentos tipo `keyword` que usando `lambda`. La otra ventaja es la eficiencia como se ha comentado, sin entrar en detalles, con `partial` se evita crear y destruir un nuevo frame en la pila por ejemplo.

```
import functools

tk.Button(command=functools.partial(write, "7"))
```

---

Como nota independiente a tu pregunta, no hagas:

```
button_7 = tk.Button(...).place(x=0, y=100)
```

esto hace que `button_7` quede asociado al retorno de `place`, que es `None`. Terminas con un montón de variables poblando tu espacio de nombres, todas asociadas a `None` y que no sirven para nada.

Si quieres hacer referencia con posterioridad a tu widget, separa la llamada a `place`/`pack`/`grid` de la instanciación:

```
button_7 = tk.Button(...)
button_7.place(x=0, y=100)
button_7.config(...)
```

si no vas a utilizar nunca una referencia al widget, simplemente no crees una nueva variable:

```
tk.Button(frame, text="7", ...).place(x=0, y=100)
tk.Button(frame, text="8", ...).place(x=124, y=100)
```