# ¿Por qué es necesario pasar le el parámetro event a la función lambda?

Tags: python, lambda

¿Porque es necesario en este caso pasar le el parámetro `event` a la función `lambda` para después pasárselo a la función?, si yo no le paso el parámetro `event` me lanza el siguiente error :

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Este código funciona para que cada vez que el `mouse` este posicionado por encima de un botón este cambie de color:

```
def on_enter(event,Button,name):    
    if name in ("A","B","C","D","E","F"):
        Button.config(bg="#3498DB",borderwidth=2,relief="groove")
    else:
        Button.config(bg="#99A3A4",borderwidth=2,relief="groove")
def on_leave(event,Button):
    Button.config(bg="SystemButtonFace",borderwidth=0)

Button_delete.bind("<Enter>",lambda event:on_enter(event,Button_delete,"A"))
Button_delete.bind("<Leave>",lambda event:on_leave(event,Button_delete))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los métodos `bind` / `bind_all` / `bind_class` permiten enlazar un determinado evento a una callback (cualquier objeto que pueda ser llamado realmente). En todos los casos al callable **se le pasa automáticamente como primer argumento una referencia el evento responsable de disparar la llamada**, por lo que siempre **el callable debe aceptar al menos un argumento posicional**, al cual se le asignará el evento, se use o no. Si esto no se hace, cuando el mainloop intenta  llamar a la callback y pasarle el evento como argumento, al no aceptar ésta ningún argumento, tienes el error mencionado:

```
def foo():
    pass

foo(7)
```

> ```
> Exception has occurred: TypeError
>     foo() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
> ```

Si tu callback no necesita más argumentos simplemente usarías la siguiente sintaxis:

```
def foo(evento):
    pass
widget.bind("<Evento>", foo)
```

Puede llamar la atención que para asociar al evento una función que recibe un argumento, no es necesario usar ninguna función envoltorio. Esto se debe a que es tkinter el que automáticamente al llamar a la función le pasa el evento como comentaba arriba, igual que se pasa la instancia de la clase de forma automática cuando la callback es un método de instancia, `widget.bind("<Evento>", self.foo)`.

Como se ha dicho si tu función requiere de más argumentos debes [usar una función que actúen como envoltorio de tu calback](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/270617/15089), dado que `bind` y similares no proporcionan ninguna forma de pasar argumentos extra a la misma. Puedes usar una función normal que solo acepte un argumento, una función anónima (lambda), `functools.partial` (la forma más eficiente), etc

```
def foo(evento, arg):
    pass

arg = "Hola"

widget.bind("<Evento>", lambda evento: foo(evento, arg))
```

en este caso no se asocia el evento a `foo` directamente, se asocia a la función `lambda`, la cual luego llama a `foo`, es decir, cuando el evento se produce se llama a la función anónima y la función anónima llama a `foo` proporcionándole los argumentos necesarios.

Pero recordemos que siempre se le pasa al callable el evento, por lo que la función envoltorio debe aceptar este argumento tal como hacía `foo` antes. Luego puedes pasarlo o no a la verdadera callback, pero el callable asociado a `bind`  sea cual sea (la función lambda en este caso), tiene que aceptar este argumento. Por ejemplo, si no vas a usar el evento o tu función no aceptara el argumento, puedes hacer simplemente:

```
def foo(arg):
    pass

arg = "Hola"

widget.bind("<Evento>", lambda _: foo(arg))
```

En este caso cuando se llama a la función lambda, se le pasa como ya sabemos el evento como primer argumento. Dicho argumento es capturado por `_` (es una convención en Python, usar `_` como identificador cuando necesitamos asociar algo a una variable pero no la vamos a usar nunca). Luego, como vemos, no se pasa el evento a `foo`, eso ya no importa, porque `foo` la llama la función lambda (la cual ha "consumido" el argumento pasado desde el mainloop).

---

### EXTRA

El evento que se pasa como argumento es una instancia de `tkinter.Event` y en muchos casos es de gran utilidad en la callback. Esto se debe a que además de identificar el evento, tiene una serie de atributos (dependiendo del evento en sí) que permiten identificar el widget en el que tuvo lugar el evento, las coordenadas dónde se produjo, teclas presionadas (eventos de teclado), etc.

Por ejemplo, al hacer click izquierdo sobre un widget el evento generado tiene los siguientes atributos:

```
{
 'serial': 12945,
 'num': 1,
 'height': '??',
 'keycode': '??',
 'state': 16,
 'time': 59083573,
 'width': '??',
 'x': 27,
 'y': 21,
 'char': '??',
 'send_event': False,
 'keysym': '??',
 'keysym_num': '??',
 'type': <EventType.ButtonPress: '4'>,
 'widget': <tkinter.Button object .!mainframe.!button25>,
 'x_root': 929,
 'y_root': 481,
 'delta': 0
}
```

por lo que en la callback podríamos por ejemplo obtener las coordenadas del click en el widget con solo hacer `x, y = evento.x, evento.y` por ejemplo.