# ¿Cual es el uso de lambda en bind de kivy python?

Tags: python, lambda, dropdownlist, kivy

Estoy aprendiendo a usar el objeto dropdown de la libreria kivy de python, este es el ejemplo de la documentación

```
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

dropdown = DropDown()
for index in range(10):
    btn = Button(text='Value %d' % index, size_hint_y=None, height=44)

    btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(btn.text))

    dropdown.add_widget(btn)
mainbutton = Button(text='Hello', size_hint=(None, None))
mainbutton.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)

dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))
runTouchApp(mainbutton)
```

Se que es una función lambda, se supone que los argumentos son arbitrarios como en una función normal, pero en el caso de la primera aparición "btn" se refiere a la instancia del mismo objeto al que están asignando la función (se que es para extraer "datos" en este caso el texto) y no un nombre equis

el segundo uso de lambda me parece mas extraño porque tiene dos argumentos, el "x" nunca ha sido declarado y ahora se esta usando.

¿Que esta pasando realmente aquí?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind` en todo momento necesita recibir **una referencia** a un callable que será llamado cuando el evento se produzca. A dicho callable, dependiendo del evento, se le pasan una serie de argumentos cuando es llamado, generalmente el widget causante del evento y adicionalmente otra información relevante sobre el evento determinado.

El uso de `lambda` en este caso no tiene nada de particular, se podrían usar funciones normales sin problemas, creo que pasar las expresiones `lambda` a su equivalente en una función normal, puede ayudar a entender que hace cada una:

### Primer uso

```
btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(btn.text))
```

equivale a:

```
def on_btn_select(btn):
    dropdown.select(btn.text)

btn.bind(on_release=on_btn_select)
```

En este caso cuando el evento se produce **se pasa de forma automática una referencia al widget causante del evento a su callback asociada**. El argumento `btn` recibe dicha instancia. No tiene por qué llamarse `btn` como la instancia generada en el `for`:

```
def on_btn_select(botón):
    dropdown.select(botón.text)

btn.bind(on_release=on_btn_select)
```

o:

```
btn.bind(on_release=lambda botón: dropdown.select(botón.text))
```

son igual de válidas y quizás no sean tan confusas. `btn`/`botón` son solo el nombre del argumento de la función, no hay más. Luego `bind` hace que cuando el evento se produce se le pase a dicho argumento la instancia del botón. Dicha callback tiene que aceptar si o si se argumento posicional, lo use o no.

### Segundo uso

```
dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))
```

equivale a:

```
def on_dropdown_select(instance, x):
    setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x)

dropdown.bind(on_select=on_dropdown_select)
```

en este caso `bind` con el evento `on_select` de un `DropDown` pasa a la callback dos argumentos de forma automática, la instancia del propio widget y el texto de la selección actual. La función pasada a bind debe aceptar ambos aunque no los use ya que se le van a intentar pasar aunque no los acepte.

De nuevo es lo mismo que antes, `instance` y `x` son solo el nombre que se le dan a los argumentos, no tienen que existir en ningún lado, son variables locales a la función que se asocian a una referencia al objeto que se le pasa a cada uno cuando es llamada, de hecho sería más apropiado:

```
dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda _, selección: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', selección))
```

o:

```
def on_dropdown_select(_, selección):
    mainbutton.text = selección

dropdown.bind(on_select=on_dropdown_select)
```

según las convenciones dado que no usamos para nada el primer argumento.

en este caso hay una peculiaridad, se pasa la instancia del `DropDown` y el texto de la selección, pero el botón principal es realmente algo externo al propio DropDown y que no podemos acceder a través de su instancia. Por esto para cambiarle el texto debemos usar la variable global `mainbutton`.

Otra posibilidad es asociar el mainbutton al propio DropDown, por ejemplo:

```
dropdown.mainbutton = mainbutton
dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda dropdown_instance, selección: setattr(
                            dropdown_instance.mainbutton, 'text', selección)
                            )
```

En el caso de usar expresiones `lambda` tenemos que usar `setattr` y no podemos asignar mediante `botón.text = "texto"` porque las expresiones `lambda` no permiten asignaciones.

Las siguientes preguntas están relacionada, aunque es para Tkinter, la idea del uso de expresiones `lambda` es en esencia la misma en ambos casos:

- [¿Cómo actuan las funciones lambda en este código?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/270617/15089)
- [¿Por qué es necesario pasar le el parámetro event a la función lambda?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/275767/15089)

Comment: Del primer lambda entiendo que yo le estoy pasando como argumento por defecto al metodo bind una función y el se auto pasa el boton en forma de "self", la funcion bind internamente le pasa la instancia del boton como argumento a la funcion que yo le pase.

Comment: Del primer lambda entiendo que yo le estoy pasando como argumento por defecto al método bind una función y el se auto pasa el botón en forma de "self", la función bind internamente le pasa la instancia del botón como argumento a la función que yo le pase.
En el segundo no veo con claridad el uso de la variable "global" `mainbutton`, porque le modifique el nombre como me sugeriste y no cambia la información del botón... ahora no entiendo porque si esos nombres son arbitrarios tengo que colocar el el `setattr` el nombre real del botón que quiero cambiar y no cualquier nombre de variable

Comment: @BBriam he editado la respuesta, error mio, efectivamente el botón (mainbutton) es un widget externo realmente al DropDown y cuando la función se llama cuando el evento on_select se produce se le pasa la instancia del DropDown no la del mainbutton (que repito, es externo al DropDown en si) por lo que necesitamos una referencia al botón para cambiarle el texto de acurdo al valor del DropDown. Es una implementación un poco confusa y distinta de otros frameworks, pero tiene la ventaja de poder usar el DropDown con otro widget para lanzarlo desde un Label a una imagen en vez de un botón.

Comment: Entiendo que es la manera en que lo implementan y ya entonces (Y), eso es lo que me confundia