# Como crear y borrar un frame desde un menú

Tags: python, tkinter

Quiero que se cree un frame al presionar el botón `Crear frame` del menú Crear y que este mismo frame se borre al presionar el botón `Borrar frame` del menú Borrar

Lo que he intentado;

```
from tkinter import Frame
from tkinter import Button
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import BOTH, YES
from tkinter import Menu
import tkinter as tk

ventana1 = Tk()

class crearFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,ventana):
        super().__init__(ventana)
        if self.winfo_exists() ==0:
            self.place(x=30,y=30)
            self.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=YES)
            self.config(bg="blue")
            print("Frame creado")

    def borrarFrame(self):
        if self.winfo_exists() == 1:
            self.destroy()
            print("Frame borrado")

menu = Menu(ventana1)

menuLista = Menu(menu,tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label="Crear",menu=menuLista)
menuLista.add_command(label="Crear frame",command=crearFrame(ventana1))

menuNotas = Menu(menu,tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label="Borrar",menu=menuNotas)
menuNotas.add_command(label="Borrar frame",command=crearFrame.borrarFrame())

ventana1.config(menu=menu)
ventana1.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código tiene algunos problemas:

- **El argumento `command` espera una referencia a un objeto que pueda ser llamado y ejecutado** cuando el menu sea pulsado  como una función o método. En `command=crearFrame(ventana1)` le pasas una instancia de tu `Frame`, deberías usar `lambda`, `functools.partial` o una función normal que haga de envoltura `command=lambda: crearFrame(ventana1)`:

  - [¿Cómo actuan las funciones lambda en este código?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/270617/15089)
- En `command=crearFrame.borrarFrame()` le pasas el retorno de `crearFrame.borrarFrame()` y no el método en si. Además llamas al método `borrarFrame()` mediante la clase y no mediante una instancia de la misma como deberías ya que es un método de instancia:

  ```
  frame = crearFrame(ventana1)
  menuNotas.add_command(label="Borrar frame",command=frame.borrarFrame)
  ```

  observa que se pasa una referencia al método de instancia no su retorno, es decir, hacemos:

  ```
  command=frame.borrarFrame
  ```

  y no:

  ```
  command=frame.borrarFrame()
                           ^^
                           ^^
  ```

  esto último haría  que se ejecutara `frame.borrarFrame()` al arrancar tu app y su retorno (`None`) se le asigna a `command`, cuando o que se debe asignar es el propio método no su retorno.

  Si lo llamas mediante la clase debes pasar tu mismo una referencia a la instancia al método (`self`).

Tienes varias formas de resolver tu problema desde usar una variable global para almacenar una referencia a la instancia del `Frame` a usar un singlenton para evitar que pueda existir más de una instancia del mismo simultáneamente. No obstante, dado que usas POO creo que lo más simple es hacer algo como lo siguiente para estructurar tu aplicación:

```
import tkinter as tk



class MyFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)
        self.config(bg="blue")
        print("Frame creado")

    def borrar(self):
        self.pack_forget()
        self.destroy()
        print("Frame borrado")


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.menu = tk.Menu(parent)
        self.menu_lista = tk.Menu(self.menu, tearoff=0)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label="Crear",menu=self.menu_lista)
        self.menu_lista.add_command(label="Crear frame",
                                    command=self.crear_frame
                                    )
        self.menu_notas = tk.Menu(self.menu, tearoff=0)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label="Borrar", menu=self.menu_notas)
        self.menu_notas.add_command(label="Borrar frame",
                                    command=self.borrar_frame
                                    )
        parent.config(menu=self.menu)
        self._frame = None

    def crear_frame(self):
        if self._frame is None:
            self._frame = MyFrame(self)

    def borrar_frame(self):
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.borrar()
            self._frame = None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ventana = tk.Tk()
    ventana.geometry("600x400")
    App(ventana).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    ventana.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!, tengo una ultima duda, alguna forma de crear y borrar el frame sin la necesidad de utilizar la clase App?, intente esto: https://pastebin.com/7SHJdvqN pero tiene el problema de que si le doy a crear 2 veces después ya no se borra