# Comandos de botones generados en un ciclo asociados a expresiones lambda se borran

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, variables, lambda

Estoy intentando hacer una interfaz con tkinter en la que se generan botones a partir de una lista. Cada botón recive un argumento `text` igual al elemento adecuado de la lista y un argumento `command` que es igual al lambda de una función que toma como argumento el mismo valor que el parámetro `text`. Los botones son pasados a una lista que después es recorrida con un bucle `for` que muestra cada botón con el método `grid`. El problema que tengo es que el atributo `text` es diferente en todos los botones, pero el `command` no. Esto hace que pulse el botón que pulse esto genere el mismo resultado. En este caso lo estoy utilizando para una aplicación para estudiar geografía. El código es el siguiente:

```py
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import time
from random import shuffle
def button_set(variable):
    global respstat
    global imagenes
    global respdin
    global puntuacion
    global imgcom
    global contador
    global n
    print(variable)
    print(imgcom)
    print(n)
    print(respdin)
    if respstat.index(variable) == imgcom.index(n):
        print("respuesta_correcta")
    else:
        print("respuesta incorrecta")
def actividad1():
    global raiz
    global respstat
    global imagenes
    global respdin
    global puntuacion
    global imgcom
    global contador
    global n
    imagenes = list(range(8))
    imgcom = list(range(8))
    shuffle(imagenes)
    respdin = ["Montes Urales", "Caucaso", "Pirineos", "Montes Escandinavos", "Alpes", "Apeninos", "Carpatos", "Alpes Dinaricos"]
    respstat = respdin 
    puntuacion = 0
    for n in imagenes:
        #raiz.()
        raiz.destroy()
        raiz = tk.Tk()
        raiz.resizable(1,0)
        raiz.title("europa")
        etiqueta1B = tk.Label(raiz, text="COMO SE LLAMA EL SISTEMA MONTAÑOSO MARCADO EN AZUL?")
        etiqueta1B.grid(row=0, column=0)
        imagen=tk.PhotoImage(file="mf{}.pgm".format(n+2))
        etiqueta2A = tk.Label(raiz, image=imagen)
        etiqueta2A.grid(row=1, column=1)
        contador = 0
        bcol = 0
        rcol = 0
        identified_buttons = []
        for i in respdin:
            identified_buttons.append(tk.Button(raiz, text=i, command=lambda:button_set(i)))
        for b in identified_buttons:
            b.grid(row=bcol+2, column=rcol)
            if bcol < 2:
                bcol+=1
            else:
                rcol+=1
                bcol=0
        raiz.mainloop()
def menu_principal():
    global raiz
    raiz = tk.Tk()
    raiz.resizable(0,0)
    raiz.title("europa")
    etiqueta1A = tk.Label(raiz, text="selecciona la actividad")
    etiqueta1A.grid(row=0, column=0)
    boton1A = tk.Button(raiz, text="relieve: como se llama", command=lambda:actividad1())
    boton1A.grid(row=1, column=0)
    raiz.mainloop()
menu_principal()
```

La función `button_set()` comprueba si el usuario a respondido correctamente.
En esa parte he añadido algunos prints para ver que iba mal. Resulto ser que todos los botones pasaban el mismo argumento posiciona: `"Alpes Dinaricos"`, en este caso el ultimo elemento de la lista usada para generar los botones (`respdin`). Para generar y mostrar los botones se utiliza el siguiente fragmento de código:

```py
bcol = 0
        rcol = 0
        identified_buttons = []
        for i in respdin:
            identified_buttons.append(tk.Button(raiz, text=i, command=lambda:button_set(i)))
        for b in identified_buttons:
            b.grid(row=bcol+2, column=rcol)
            if bcol < 2:
                bcol+=1
            else:
                rcol+=1
                bcol=0
```

No entiendo que es lo que ocurre, ya que si cada botón se sobrescribiese sobre los otros el texto también seria el mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema bastante común cuando se generan expresiones `lambda` en el contexto de un ciclo, tu le pasas una expresión `lambda` al argumento `command` de los botones generados en el `for`:

```
command=lambda:button_set(i)
```

esperando que el valor de `i` se evalúe en el momento que la expresión `lambda` es definida (una en cada iteración del `for`), por lo tanto cada `lambda` se asocie a una variable `i` con un valor distinto.

El problema es que **la expresión lambda no se evalúa en tiempo de definición, sino cuando es ejecutada (en este caso cuando el botón es pulsado)**. La variable libre `i` está vinculada en el momento de la ejecución de la expresión `lambda`, eso significa que todas las `lambda` definidas en ese ciclo al ser ejecutadas (cuando su botón es pulsado) acceden al valor de `i` **en ese momento**, que lógicamente es el valor asignado en la última iteración del `for`.

El texto si que cambia por una razón muy simple, el constructor de `Button` recibe mediante el argumento `text` una referencia al objeto al que está asociado `i` en esa iteración, como en cada iteración se reasigna un nuevo objeto a `i` cada llamada al constructor de `Button` recibe un objeto distinto y es ese el que usa para generar el botón inmediatamente después.

Primero voy a crear un pequeño ejemplo muy simplificado para probar las soluciones:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x300")

for i in range(5):
    tk.Button(text=str(i), command=lambda: print(i)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

como en tu caso, pulsemos el botón que pulsemos, se imprime 4 (valor de `i` tras terminar el ciclo `for`):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tienes varias soluciones:

- Usar argumentos con valor por defecto. Una expresión `lambda` se  puede inicializar con un valor predeterminado para un argumento igual que una función "normal". Como este **valor predeterminado o por defecto es evaluado en "tiempo de definición"**, si no pasamos ningún valor al argumento al llamarla, se usa el valor por defecto y solventa el problema mencionado. Puedes hacer lo mismo usando una función normal (definida con `def`) en vez de `lambda` ya que, igualmente, el cuerpo de la función es evaluado cuando es ejecutada y no cuando es definida.

  ```
  import tkinter as tk

  root = tk.Tk()
  root.geometry("200x300")

  for i in range(5):
      tk.Button(text=str(i), command=lambda i=i: print(i)).pack()

  root.mainloop()
  ```

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Usar [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.partial) en vez de `lambda`, que para estos casos (valores de variables conocidos en tiempo de definición) es la mejor opción, además de más eficiente:

  ```
  import functools
  import tkinter as tk

  root = tk.Tk()
  root.geometry("200x300")

  for i in range(5):
      tk.Button(text=str(i), command=functools.partial(print, i)).pack()

  root.mainloop()
  ```

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por cierto, no envuelvas a una función o método con una expresión lambda si no necesitas pasar argumentos. No sirve de nada y es ineficiente, en vez de:

```
command=lambda:actividad1()
```

debes hacer simplemente:

```
command=lactividad1
```

Para más información, puedes mirarte:

- [¿Cómo actuan las funciones lambda en este código?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/270617/15089)