# Quisiera obtener el valor de varios campos de texto

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy creando un código que acepte datos para cada año desde 2015 hasta un año que escoja el usuario

Mi problema es que estoy haciendo la interfaz por un método iterativo (con `for`) y cuando quiero obtener el valor que el usuario ingresó, solo obtengo el del último campo de texto. Me gustaría que un solo botón obtuviera todos los valores de los campos de texto que hubiera.

Mi problema está en la función `Intereses`:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

   anio=2020
   inv = tk.Tk()
   inv.title("Mi ventana")

   inv.minsize(500, 250)
   Label(inv,text="").grid(row=0,column=0)
   Label(inv,text="").grid(row=1,column=1)   
   for i in range(2015,anio+1):

           a=i-2015
           a=a+3
           Label(inv,text="Selecione la tasa de inflación porcentual para el año ").grid(row=a,column=1)
           Label(inv,text=i).grid(row=a,column=2)
           txt = Entry(inv,width=7)
           txt.grid(column=3, row=a)
           but = ttk.Button(inv, text = "Guardar tasas de interés ",command=lambda: print(txt.get()))
           but.grid(column = 4,row = 15)
inv.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hola. De hecho me gustaría que un solo botón obtuviera todos los valores de los campos de texto que hubiera

Answer (score 0):

La causa de que solo muestre el contenido del último se debe a lo explicado en:

- [Comandos de botones generados en un ciclo asociados a expresiones lambda se borran](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/331975/15089)

No obstante, usas el enfoque equivocado para lo que quieres conseguir. En vez de generar un botón en cada iteración, debes generar un solo botón y usar una lista para almacenar las instancias de `Entry` generadas de forma dinámica en el `for`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


año = 2020

inv = tk.Tk()
inv.title("Mi ventana")
inv.minsize(500, 250)



tk.Label(inv,text="").grid(row=0,column=0)
tk.Label(inv,text="").grid(row=1,column=1)  

entries = [] 
for i in range(2015, año + 1):
    a = i - 2015
    a = a + 3
    (tk.Label(inv, text="Selecione la tasa de inflación porcentual para el año ")
        .grid(row=a,column=1)
        )
    tk.Label(inv, text = i).grid(row=a, column=2)
    txt = tk.Entry(inv, width=7)
    txt.grid(column=3, row=a)
    entries.append(txt)


def get_entries(entries):
    for entry in entries:
        print(entry.get())

but = ttk.Button(inv,
                 text="Guardar tasas de interés ",
                 command=lambda: get_entries(entries)
                 )
but.grid(column=4, row=a + 1)

inv.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mil gracias!!!!