# ¿Cómo establecer la altura y el ancho de un botón de acuerdo con el tamaño de la ventana? Problema con row-columnconfiguration

Tags: python, tkinter

Estaba tratando de programar una especie de calculadora en Python usando la biblioteca Tkinter. Mi problema es que veo algunas páginas que dicen que la forma de configurar el ancho y el grosor de un botón es usar la configuración de fila y la configuración de columna. El problema es que cuando ejecuto el script no funciona. No sé lo que estoy haciendo mal, así que por favor ayúdenme

Aquí está el código.

```
import tkinter as tk


def insert_number(variable, entry):
    result = variable + entry
    return result


conjunt = ""


class MainWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.grid()

        self.config(bg="blue")
        self.button1 = tk.Button(text="1", command=insert_number(conjunt, "1")).grid(
            column=0, row=0)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(text="2", command=insert_number(conjunt, "2")).grid(
            column=1, row=0)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(text="3", command=insert_number(conjunt, "3")).grid(
            column=2, row=0)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(text="4", command=insert_number(conjunt, "1")).grid(
            column=0, row=1)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(text="5", command=insert_number(conjunt, "1")).grid(
            column=1, row=1)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(text="6", command=insert_number(conjunt, "1")).grid(
            column=2, row=1)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(text="7", command=insert_number(conjunt, "1")).grid(
            column=0, row=2)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(text="8", command=insert_number(conjunt, "1")).grid(
            column=1, row=2)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(text="9", command=insert_number(conjunt, "1")).grid(
            column=2, row=2)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(text="0", command=insert_number(conjunt, "1")).grid(
            column=1, row=3)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)




    def give_result(self):
        pass


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Calculadora")

    buttons_frame = MainWindow(root)
    buttons_frame.grid()

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que los botones se adapten al tamaño de la ventana de forma automáica necesitas varias cosas:

- Al constructor de `Button` le debes pasar una referencia al padre (en este caso la instancia de la case `MainWindow`, `self`). **Pasa siempre el padre a todo widget que crees**, si no lo haces se posicionaran en la ventana principal (`tkinter.Tk`).
- Para que los botones se adapten al tamaño de la ventana debes hacer que su padre también lo haga.
- Además de asignar un peso distinto de 0 a cada columna y fila mediante `rowconfigure` y `columnconfigure`, debes especificar en la llamada a `grid` que el widget ocupe todo el espacio del que disponga. Esto se hace mediante el argumento `sticky` con el valor "NSEW"

Con lo anterior se resuelve el problema comentado, pero tienes otro error no relacionado con tu problema original. **A `command` se le pasa la referencia a la función (o callable cualquiera) a llamar cuando el botón se pulsa**. En tu caso haces lo siguiente:

```
    command=insert_number(conjunt, "1")
```

esto hace que al ejecutar el script (cuando aun no se ha mostrado ni la app) se llame a `insert_number` y `command` recibe su retorno (una cadena). Usa `lambda` o `functools.partial` para usar callables con argumentos:

- [¿Cómo actuan las funciones lambda en este código?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/270617/15089)

El código quedaría como:

```
import tkinter as tk


def insert_number(variable, entry):
    result = variable + entry
    return result


conjunt = ""


class MainWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self.config(bg="blue")
        tk.Button(self, text="1", command=lambda: insert_number(conjunt, "1")).grid(
            column=0, row=0, sticky="NSEW")
        tk.Button(self, text="2", command=lambda: insert_number(conjunt, "2")).grid(
            column=1, row=0, sticky="NSEW")
        tk.Button(self, text="3", command=lambda: insert_number(conjunt, "3")).grid(
            column=2, row=0, sticky="NSEW")
        tk.Button(self, text="4", command=lambda: insert_number(conjunt, "4")).grid(
            column=0, row=1, sticky="NSEW")
        tk.Button(self, text="5", command=lambda: insert_number(conjunt, "5")).grid(
            column=1, row=1, sticky="NSEW")
        tk.Button(self, text="6", command=lambda: insert_number(conjunt, "6")).grid(
            column=2, row=1, sticky="NSEW")
        tk.Button(self, text="7", command=lambda: insert_number(conjunt, "7")).grid(
            column=0, row=2, sticky="NSEW")
        tk.Button(self, text="8", command=lambda: insert_number(conjunt, "8")).grid(
            column=1, row=2, sticky="NSEW")
        tk.Button(self, text="9", command=lambda: insert_number(conjunt, "9")).grid(
            column=2, row=2, sticky="NSEW")
        tk.Button(self, text="0",  command=lambda: insert_number(conjunt, "0")).grid(
            column=1, row=3, sticky="NSEW")

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)




    def give_result(self):
        pass


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Calculadora")

    buttons_frame = MainWindow(root)
    buttons_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSEW")
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda amigo! Entendí bien tu explicación. Había visitado varias páginas en inglés y español y no encontraba el problema. Una pregunta a parte del asunto ¿Usas Linux? Lo digo por el tema del marco de la ventana, se ve genial.

Comment: De nada. Si, uso Linux en este caso, [Manjaro](https://manjaro.org/) con [KDE Plasma](https://kde.org/plasma-desktop) como entorno de escritorio pero con mil cosas personalizadas, el escritorio se parece muy poco al original XD.

Comment: Lol. Creo que voy a instalar ese OS en una maquina virtual y personalizarlo. Aunque nunca he usado Linux jajaja