# NameError: name 'entrada1' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, zip

Estoy creando un programa que pueda descomprimir y comprimir archivos "zip", con modulo Tkinter.

Cuando intento abrir un archivo, el intérprete me indica:

> "NameError: name 'entrada1' is not defined".

Os dejo mi código por si sirve de ayuda:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from zipfile import ZipFile
from tkinter import filedialog

#creacion de widgets
def widgets():
    etiqueta1 = Label(ventana, text ="Archivo a Descomprimir:", bg = "steelblue", font = ("", 10, "bold"))
    etiqueta1.grid(row=0,column=0, padx = 5, pady=5)
    entrada1 = Entry(ventana, width = 30, font = ("Arial")). grid(row=0,column=1, columnspan = 2, padx = 5, pady=5)
    boton1 = Button(ventana, text = "Abrir", width = 15, command = navegar).grid(row=0,column=3, padx = 5, pady=5)

    etiqueta2 = Label(ventana, text ="Nombre Carpeta:", bg = "steelblue", font = ("",10, "bold"))
    etiqueta2.grid(row=1,column=0, padx = 5, pady=5)
    entrada2 = Entry(ventana, width = 30, font = ("Arial")).grid(row=1,column=1, columnspan = 2, padx = 5, pady=5)
    boton2 = Button(ventana, text = "Descomprimir", width = 15).grid(row=1,column=3, padx = 5, pady=5)

def navegar():
    abrir = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "C:\\Users\\Fran\\Desktop")
    entrada1.insert("1.0", "Los siguientes archivos seran descomprimidos\n")
    nombrearchivo = os.path.basename(abrir)
    entrada1.insert("2.0", nombrearchivo)
    entrada1.config(state=DISABLED)

#ventana
ventana = Tk()
ventana.title("Compresor/Descompresor")
ventana.config(background = "steelblue")
widgets()
ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Te recomiendo hacer el recorrido para averiguar como realizar una pregunta que cumpla los requisitos mínimos de calidad en SO. Te dejo aquí el enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Gracias, me estaba liando un poco para introducir el código. Entonces decidí ponerlo en imágenes

Comment: Nadie va a replicar tu problema si tiene que transcribir desde una imagen. Por favor, cámbialas por texto. Gracias!

Comment: Hola frank, bienvenido a [es.so]. Como te han comentado el código debe ir siempre como texto, simplemente lo copias y lo pegas, luego lo seleccionas todo y pulsas Ctrl + k o el botón {} del editor. Si tienes problemas para formatearlo, no te preocupes, dejalo como puedas y seguro que otro usuario editará la respuesta para corregirlo, mejor eso que usar imágenes. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte. Usando "Ctrl + k" he podido ponerlo bien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas importantes:

### Llamar a `grid`/`pack`/`place` en la misma línea dónde se instancia

Hacer lo siguiente:

```
entrada1 = Entry(ventana, ....).grid(...)
```

es un error muy común cuando se empieza con Tkinter. Veamos que hace ese código por partes y en el orden en el que es evaluado:

1. `Entry(ventana, ....)`: se crea una instancia de la clase `tkinter.Entry` y es retornado dicho objeto.
2. `.grid(...)`: llama al **método de instancia** `grid` del objeto `Entry` recién creado, lo cual posiciona el widget  y `retorna`None.
3. `entrada1 = ...`: asignamos a la variable `entrada1` el retorno del método, es decir `None`.

El resultado es un montón de variables, todas apuntando a `None` que no sirven absolutamente para nada. Ya no podremos referenciar al objeto con ella...

Si quieres poder referenciar el `Entry` (o cualquier widget) en un futuro, llama a place después de asignar el objeto a la variable:

```
entrada1 = Entry(ventana, ....)
entrada1.grid(...)
```

si no vas a usar nunca la referencia al widget, no crees una variable:

```
Entry(ventana, ....).grid(...)
```

### Variables definidas en una función son locales a la misma

El segundo error es que `entrada1` es una variable definida dentro de la función `widgets`. Una variable definida dentro de una función si no se indica lo contrario es siempre local a la misma, ésto implica que dejará de existir en cuanto la función retorne y que no podrá accederse a ella desde fuera de la misma.

Por eso, cuando luego en navegar intentas acceder a ella en:

```
entrada1.insert(...)
```

tienes el mencionado error:

> NameError: name 'entrada1' is not defined

y es que `entrada1` se definió localmente cuando se llamó a `widgets`, cuando ésta retornó desapareció, además no hay una variable global con ese nombre ni tampoco la declaras dentro de `navegar` antes de intentar usarla, por lo que no existe.

### Un `Entry` no admite varias lineas de texto

Si quieres poder mostrar varias lineas de texto usa un `Label` (solo salida) o un widget `Text` (entrada y salida). Un `Entry` solo admite una línea de texto.

Para solventar tu error tienes varias opciones:

- **Indicarle a la función que trate a la variable como global**

  ```
  import os
  import tkinter as tk
  from zipfile import ZipFile
  from tkinter import filedialog


  def widgets():
      global entrada1
      tk.Label(
          ventana, text="Archivo a Descomprimir:",
          bg="steelblue", font=("", 10, "bold")
          ).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

      entrada1 = tk.Entry(ventana, width=30, font="Arial")
      entrada1.grid(row=0,column=1, columnspan = 2, padx = 5, pady=5)

      tk.Button(ventana, text = "Abrir", width = 15, command=navegar).grid(
          row=0,column=3, padx = 5, pady=5
          )

      tk.Label(
          ventana, text="Nombre Carpeta:",
          bg="steelblue", font=("", 10, "bold")
          ).grid(row=1,column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

      entrada2 = tk.Entry(ventana, width=30, font="Arial")
      entrada2.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)

      tk.Button(ventana, text="Descomprimir", width=15).grid(
          row=1, column=3, padx=5, pady=5
          )


  def navegar():
      global entrada1
      abrir = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/Fran/Desktop")
      nombrearchivo = os.path.basename(abrir)
      entrada1.insert(tk.END, nombrearchivo)

  #ventana
  ventana = tk.Tk()
  ventana.title("Compresor/Descompresor")
  ventana.config(background="steelblue")
  widgets()
  ventana.mainloop()
  ```

  El uso de variables globales no es generalmente buena práctica y debe evitarse en lo posible. Se deberían reducir su uso a constantes o como mucho a variables de estado del módulo.
- **Pasarle a la función una referencia al widget o widgets que necesite como argumentos**

  ```
  import os
  import tkinter as tk
  from zipfile import ZipFile
  from tkinter import filedialog


  def widgets():
      tk.Label(
          ventana, text="Archivo a Descomprimir:",
          bg="steelblue", font=("", 10, "bold")
          ).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

      entrada1 = tk.Entry(ventana, width=30, font="Arial")
      entrada1.grid(row=0,column=1, columnspan = 2, padx = 5, pady=5)

      tk.Button(
          ventana, text = "Abrir", width = 15,
          command=lambda: navegar(entrada1)).grid(
              row=0,column=3, padx = 5, pady=5
              )

      tk.Label(
          ventana, text="Nombre Carpeta:",
          bg="steelblue", font=("", 10, "bold")
          ).grid(row=1,column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

      entrada2 = tk.Entry(ventana, width=30, font="Arial")
      entrada2.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)

      tk.Button(ventana, text="Descomprimir", width=15).grid(
          row=1, column=3, padx=5, pady=5
          )

  def navegar(entrada):
      abrir = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/Fran/Desktop")
      nombrearchivo = os.path.basename(abrir)
      entrada.insert(tk.END, nombrearchivo)


  #ventana
  ventana = tk.Tk()
  ventana.title("Compresor/Descompresor")
  ventana.config(background="steelblue")
  widgets()
  ventana.mainloop()
  ```

  para entender el uso de lambda aquí puedes mirarte:

  - [¿Cómo actuan las funciones lambda en este código?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/270617/15089)
- **Usar programación orientada a objetos y que tus variables sean atributos de instancia**

  ```
  import os
  import tkinter as tk
  from zipfile import ZipFile
  from tkinter import filedialog


  class MyZip(tk.Frame):
      def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
          super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

          tk.Label(
              self, text="Archivo a Descomprimir:",
              bg="steelblue", font=("", 10, "bold")
              ).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

          self.entrada1 = tk.Entry(self, width=30, font="Arial")
          self.entrada1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)

          tk.Button(self, text="Abrir",
                    width=15, command=self.navegar
                    ).grid(row=0,column=3, padx = 5, pady=5)

          tk.Label(
              self, text="Nombre Carpeta:",
              bg="steelblue", font=("", 10, "bold")
              ).grid(row=1,column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

          self.entrada2 = tk.Entry(self, width=30, font="Arial")
          self.entrada2.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)

          tk.Button(self, text="Descomprimir", width=15).grid(
              row=1, column=3, padx=5, pady=5
              )

      def navegar(self):
          abrir = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/Fran/Desktop")
          nombrearchivo = os.path.basename(abrir)
          self.entrada1.insert(tk.END, nombrearchivo)


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      ventana = tk.Tk()
      ventana.title("Compresor/Descompresor")
      MyZip(ventana, background="steelblue").pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
      ventana.mainloop()
  ```

  Posiblemnte la mejor opción y la más escalable. No obstante, si estás empezando puede que sea un salto demasiado grande de golpe.